# php for insert same several data with diiferent code number

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have this kind of output table of code asset and asset name

```
+------------+------------+
| code asset | asset name |
+------------+------------+
|     001    | computer   |
|     001    | computer   |
|     002    | laptop     |
+------------+------------+
```

for example i want to fill the form same computer but i wanted to show different code asset,what did i get was when i entered the quantity of the computer,it duplicate the code number. it suppose to be like this

```
+------------+------------+
| code asset | asset name |
+------------+------------+
|     001    | computer   |
|     002    | computer   |
|     003    | laptop     |
+------------+------------+
```

The form is like this

```
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Asset Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="assetname">
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

i'm using for loop. the action is like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < $_POST['quantity']; $i++) {
    $inAset = inaset($nosiri,$_POST['assetname']);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
    if($inAset != 1) echo mysql_error();
}//for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time creating the table you need to add primary key on your first column and add auto increment to the column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (code_asset INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, col_name VARCHAR(20),...)
```

It will automatically add +1 to the next row....

Comment: explanation: this will ensure atomicity of the operations instead of relying the php (that can have several request at once) to check the latest `code_asset` and increment it. so, the idea is, 1. register the asset first to database; 2. then store the file with using the code_asset as name or something random to prevent replacing existing files. seconds late, lol..

Comment: my code asset is not the primary key but it just as references for the asset.